# getbounds on google api v2 is not working

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

getbounds() return error on firebug. May I know what is the problem? Thanks.

```
map=new GMap2(document.getElementbyId('map'));
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(la,lo),15);
map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl3D());
map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
map.enableScrollWheelZoom();
var bounds = map.getBounds();
var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
var southEast = bounds.getSouthEast();
var northWest = bounds.getNorthWest();
```

Firebug states that getSouthWest() is not a functions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should wait until the map fires `load` event.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple problem here is that GLatLngBounds only has getSouthWest() and getNorthEast() methods, not getSouthEast() and getNorthWest() (see the [API reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html#GLatLngBounds)). Are you sure Firebug is giving you an error on getSouthWest? I am able to get your code working without an error if I remove the last two function calls.